# ESP32 can't connect to site with a changed SSL cert

Tags: github, ssl, https, esp32

So I have a bunch of ESP32 devices that use GitHub to update its firmware. It has the root certificate of GitHub hardcoded in it so it can make an HTTPS request. Unfortunately, I misread the expiry of the root certificate and GitHub has just renewed their certificate. Now I can't push an update to any of my devices because it can't reach GitHub. As I have many of these devices scattered around, is there anything I can do to overcome this?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The only information here are that you relied on a specific CA certificate which is out of your control (sounds like a bad idea from start) and then the certificate is no longer there. The only option based on this information is that you need the old certificate back, which is impossible since it is out of your control. Maybe there are other options, but not based on the information provided by you.

Comment: From my understanding, we can't have a CA in an ESP32, so most of the time root certificate is hardcoded into the firmware. I do still have the old certificate, but since Github updated their certificate, the ESP32 device is unable to pull any updates from the repo.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about the root CA and not the server certificate? The root CA gets only updated in very long intervals (many many years), while the server certificate gets updated regularly (several month up to a year). As far as I can see there was no update of the github root CA.

Comment: (@SteffenUllrich) according to the transparency log at crt.sh they used DigiCert since 2011 but switched to Sectigo-was-Comodo, and thus the legacy UserTrust or AAACert roots, a few days ago for the website and about a month ago for email. My logs confirm the website was using DigiCert in mid-2022, and now I see Sectigo.

Comment: I'm sorry this has happened to you. Unless there is *another* bug in your ESP32 software, it seems you are out of luck. You will have to physically go to each device to update them. I'm not an expert in the state-of-the-art for designing security for fielded devices, but I think Steffan has alluded to the critical mistake: you need to control the CA certificate, and you should probably also have a backup certificate. That likely means you also need to control a domain that you use for updates. Perhaps that domain just proxies traffic to GitHub, but it still needs to be under your control.